# Facebook Javascript Share Dialog Shows Image but not Title, Description

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Javascript API to display a share dialog box that displays a link to a freshly generated image. The code looks like this e.g.:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'http://website.com/image.png',
      title: 'TITLE',
      description: 'DESCRIPTION',
      caption: 'CAPTION',
      }, function(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id){}
        else{}
      });
```

This works, except that the image is displayed WITHOUT the TITLE or DESCRIPTION text.

[image: share link with image]

However, if I do this (NOTE: It's a regular link, not an image):

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          href: 'http://website.com',
          title: 'TITLE',
          description: 'DESCRIPTION',
          caption: 'CAPTION',
        }, function(response) {
            if(response && response.post_id){}
            else{}
          });
```

...then the text is displayed correctly. And when I go to the facebook debugger everything looks good as well.

My question is how can I get the Title and Description to appear underneath the image?

I had heard the the share.php script can sometimes yield different results but so far I've seen the same behavior.

I'm pretty sure this is possible because I've seen websites that do this. And even Facebook's documentation shows an example that does this...

[image: Facebook Example]

Which came from this page:
[A Guide to Sharing for Webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Comment: I think that comes from your webpage title and description tag

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, I'm not having any trouble with the text that it's using. When I use a non-image link, it picks up the correct text, but when the link is an image Facebook hides the text.

Comment: can I view this online?

Comment: This depends of your og tags, can you please share your link so we can take a look? You can also use the FB debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks for responding. The site is not live yet and not public so I can't share. I was able to get the title and description to display once I had the og tags in place and created pages for each image, but I'm just wondering why the title and description are ignored in the API call? Will post my solution soon in case it's helpful to anyone else.